# Network performace with RTL8192SU

Tags: networking, raspbmc

I have a Model B (256MB) using a D-Link DWA-131 USB wireless-N adapater (Realtek RTL8192SU) via an external powered hub, running Raspbmc 12 (latest build, installed only a few days ago).

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c51b Logitech, Inc. V220 Cordless Optical Mouse for Notebooks
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 07d1:3303 D-Link System DWA-131 802.11n Wireless N Nano Adapter(rev.A1) [Realtek RTL8192SU]
```

My N300 router is configured as mixed g and n, channel 6, no guest mode, WPA2 and AES only.

First, when I run `sudo iwlist scanning`, the interface claims that the maximum bit rate is 54 Mb/s:

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo iwlist scanning
wlan0     Scan completed :
Cell 01 - Address: C8:BE:19:75:3E:7A
                ESSID:"Gurunetwork"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Extra:rsn_ie=<redacted>
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: <redacted>
                Signal level=100/100
```

I believe my router is properly configured to support faster than 54Mb/s, so is there anything I can change in the Pi network settings to get the speed up?

Secondly, when streaming large files, if I check what's happening with `ifconfig`, I see lots of packet loss.

I tested with `iperf` and noticed the following:

- 10Mbit/sec - no loss
- 15Mbit/sec - no loss
- 20Mbit/sec - 22-30% packet loss

Here are the logs:

```
[  3] local 192.168.0.101 port 5001 connected with 192.168.0.100 port 57336
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4] local 192.168.0.101 port 5001 connected with 192.168.0.100 port 49462
[  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec  1.19 MBytes  10.0 Mbits/sec   1.089 ms    0/  850 (0%)
[  4]  1.0- 2.0 sec  1.18 MBytes  9.90 Mbits/sec   1.497 ms    0/  842 (0%)
[  4]  2.0- 3.0 sec  1.19 MBytes  10.0 Mbits/sec   1.280 ms    0/  850 (0%)
[  4]  3.0- 4.0 sec  1.20 MBytes  10.1 Mbits/sec   1.171 ms    0/  855 (0%)
[  4]  4.0- 5.0 sec  1.19 MBytes  9.98 Mbits/sec   1.116 ms    0/  849 (0%)
[  4]  0.0- 5.0 sec  5.96 MBytes  9.99 Mbits/sec   1.249 ms    0/ 4250 (0%)
[  4]  0.0- 5.0 sec  1 datagrams received out-of-order

[  3] local 192.168.0.101 port 5001 connected with 192.168.0.100 port 62321
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  1.52 MBytes  12.7 Mbits/sec   1.271 ms    0/ 1082 (0%)
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  1.99 MBytes  16.7 Mbits/sec   0.983 ms    0/ 1423 (0%)
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  1.79 MBytes  15.0 Mbits/sec   1.177 ms    0/ 1279 (0%)
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  1.79 MBytes  15.0 Mbits/sec   0.960 ms    0/ 1277 (0%)
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  1.79 MBytes  15.0 Mbits/sec   0.960 ms    0/ 1275 (0%)
[  3]  0.0- 5.0 sec  8.89 MBytes  14.9 Mbits/sec   1.048 ms    0/ 6338 (0%)
[  3]  0.0- 5.0 sec  1 datagrams received out-of-order

[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  1.58 MBytes  13.3 Mbits/sec   0.943 ms  226/ 1355 (17%)
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  1.83 MBytes  15.3 Mbits/sec   1.098 ms  488/ 1790 (27%)
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  1.96 MBytes  16.4 Mbits/sec   1.284 ms  277/ 1673 (17%)
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  2.01 MBytes  16.9 Mbits/sec   1.022 ms  273/ 1710 (16%)
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  1.57 MBytes  13.2 Mbits/sec   1.222 ms  529/ 1652 (32%)
[  3]  0.0- 5.2 sec  9.28 MBytes  15.0 Mbits/sec   0.932 ms 1874/ 8496 (22%)
[  3]  0.0- 5.2 sec  1 datagrams received out-of-order
```

I considered trying to update the Realtek driver, but found that there are some XBMC dependencies that don't play nicely if you `sudo apt-get update` (I had to wipe and reinstall Raspbmc). Is there a good way to update just the Realtek driver without using `apt-get`, so that I can narrow the problem down to hardware or software?

Comment: My rt8192 based WiFi dongle connects with 150MBit/s to my router, but I still don't get more than 1-2 MByte/s. Lots of neighbour WiFis though. I think you may not get that much more performance out of WiFi.

Comment: Ditto Arne: no one really gets 10 and 20 MB/s rates. Do you have a comparison to another device on the same WLAN?  Using `upgrade` couldn't help you unless the update includes a kernel update, which the does not seem to happen very often with the raspbian kernels (in fact, I don't think it has happened at all since 3.2.27+).

Comment: Umm... How were you able to reach even 20 Mbps? My internet speed (any info coming in via Ethernet) maxes out at around 1 Mbps.

Comment: iperf sets the speed and generates the packets. It's an internal network speed test. I have a NAS with a gigabit wired connection to my n router, so if I'm streaming from the NAS it's the wireless connection that's (presumably) the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your router is in b/g/n mixed mode which will not perform up to n standards even with an n device; I use 2 WLANs at home, one in mixed mode for non-n devices and one exlclusively n mode for the n capable things.

If you google "mixed mode packet loss" you'll find various stories similar to yours.

Comment: Hmmm. I specifically disabled b in the router setup (it should only be g and n). That being said, a completely separate router for g may not be a bad idea.

Comment: Splitting the network to b/g and n APs allowed the Pi to connect at 150Mbit/s *and* even at 40M/s with iperf, the packet loss is maximum 2%. Bravo!